# How to get ADF app function output to use it in the further pipline process?

Tags: python, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I'm new in Azure so I have some gaps in my knowledge. I've been looking for answer but couldn't find one.

Within my app function which is HTTP TRIGGERED I do make some api call to retrieve json. If everything goes fine, then the function returns this json.

Pseudo code:

```
return func.HttpResponse(
    json.dumps(apiReturn),
    status_code=200
)
```

I'd like then to use this json (return) to store it in nsql db or csv for further processing. Is this possible somehow or I just need to create separate json file on function stage and upload it to blob storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! you can store it into blob storage using Blob bindings found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=python

You can also take a look at this to find more examples:
https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/tree/master/v2functions/queue-trigger-blob-in-out-binding

Long story short, what you have to do is:

1. Change your function.json to take in blobs
2. Change your code to take in an input blob
3. Add your blob keys to both your local.settings.json as well as on your function app in the portal configuration.

and that should get you where you need to go!